# Why does gadgetfs sometimes fail with EBUSY when I reply to a string request?

Tags: linux, usb, gadgetfs

I have a Variscite DART-MX8M evaluation board that I'm trying to use as a USB gadget, so I've written a user-mode gadget driver which talks to gadgetfs (mounted on `/dev/gadget`).  It always returns a device descriptor to the host machine, but sometimes fails when responding to a requests for a string descriptor.  The symptom is that when I write the string back to endpoint 0, I get `EBUSY`; it doesn't help to retry, as the subsequent attempt gets `ESRCH`.

It doesn't happen on the first request for the string descriptor, as you see lower down where the host gets the manufacturer and vendor (via udev rules, I think) but `lsusb` fails to retrieve them.  But when it does fail, it's always at the same point in the execution.

I've done some print-tracing in the kernel (5.4.85, Variscite's "Dunfell" release) and found [where the `EBUSY` originates](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.85/source/drivers/usb/dwc3/ep0.c#L207):

> ```c
>     /* we share one TRB for ep0/1 */
>     if (!list_empty(&dep->pending_list)) {
>       ret = -EBUSY;
>       goto out;
>     }
> ```

But I don't understand why we might hit this.

I made the simplest driver I could to reproduce this - it has just one configuration, with no endpoints (not counting ep0):

```c
#include <linux/usb/ch9.h>
#include <linux/usb/gadgetfs.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define USB_DEV "/dev/gadget/dwc3-gadget"

enum string_id {
    STRINGID_MANUFACTURER = 1,
    STRINGID_PRODUCT,
    STRINGID_SERIAL,
};

static const char *get_string_descriptor(enum string_id sid)
{
    static const char mfr[] = { 10, USB_DT_STRING, 84, 0, 111, 0, 98, 0, 121, 0};
    static const char prod[] = { 16, USB_DT_STRING, 119, 0, 105, 0, 100, 0, 103, 0, 101, 0, 116, 0};
    static const char ser[] = { 8, USB_DT_STRING, 118, 0, 49, 0};
    switch (sid) {
    case STRINGID_MANUFACTURER:
        return mfr;
    case STRINGID_PRODUCT:
        return prod;
    case STRINGID_SERIAL:
        return ser;
    }

    static const char fallback[] = { 20, USB_DT_STRING, 40, 0, 109, 0, 105, 0,
        115, 0, 115, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 41, 0 };
    return fallback;
}

static int write_string_descriptor(int fd, enum string_id sid) {
    const char *buf = get_string_descriptor(sid);
    return write(fd, buf, buf[0]);
}

static void handle_setup_request(int fd, struct usb_ctrlrequest* setup)
{
    int status;
    uint8_t buffer[512];
    pthread_t thread;

    printf("Setup request %d\n", setup->bRequest);

    switch (setup->bRequest) {
    case USB_REQ_GET_DESCRIPTOR:
        if (setup->bRequestType != USB_DIR_IN)
            goto stall;
        switch (setup->wValue >> 8) {
        case USB_DT_STRING:
            printf("Get string id #%d(max length %d)\n", setup->wValue & 0xff,
                   setup->wLength);
            status = write_string_descriptor(fd, setup->wValue & 0xff);
            // Error
            if (status < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write string descriptor %d\n", setup->wValue & 0xff);
            }
            return;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot return descriptor %d\n", (setup->wValue >> 8));
        }
        break;
    case USB_REQ_SET_CONFIGURATION:
        printf("Ignoring configuration value %d\n", setup->wValue);
        // Just ACK
        status = read(fd, &status, 0);
        return;
    case USB_REQ_GET_INTERFACE:
        printf("GET_INTERFACE\n");
        buffer[0] = 0;
        write(fd, buffer, 1);
        return;
    case USB_REQ_SET_INTERFACE:
        printf("SET_INTERFACE\n");
        // ACK
        status = read(fd, &status, 0);
        return;
    }

 stall:
    fprintf(stderr, "Stalled\n");
    // Error
    if (setup->bRequestType & USB_DIR_IN)
        read (fd, &status, 0);
    else
        write (fd, &status, 0);
}

static void handle_ep0(int fd)
{
    while (1) {
        struct usb_gadgetfs_event events[5];

        int readsize = read(fd, &events, sizeof events);
        if (readsize < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Read error %d(%m)\n", readsize);
            return;
        }

        const int nevents = readsize / sizeof events[0];
        int surplus = readsize % sizeof events[0];
        printf("%d event(s) and %d extra\n", nevents, surplus);

        for (int i = 0;  i < nevents;  ++i) {
            switch (events[i].type) {
            case GADGETFS_CONNECT:
                printf("EP0 CONNECT\n");
                break;
            case GADGETFS_DISCONNECT:
                printf("EP0 DISCONNECT\n");
                break;
            case GADGETFS_SETUP:
                printf("EP0 SETUP\n");
                handle_setup_request(fd, &events[i].u.setup);
                break;
            case GADGETFS_NOP:
            case GADGETFS_SUSPEND:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int fd = open(USB_DEV, O_RDWR|O_SYNC|O_EXCL);
    if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s(%m)\n", USB_DEV);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const struct usb_device_descriptor device_descriptor =
        { .bLength = USB_DT_DEVICE_SIZE,
          .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_DEVICE,
          .bDeviceClass = USB_CLASS_COMM,
          .bDeviceSubClass = 0,
          .bDeviceProtocol = 0,
          .idVendor = 0xAA00, // Fake vendor ID
          .idProduct = 0xBB, // Fake product ID
          .bcdDevice = 0x0200, // Version
          .iManufacturer = STRINGID_MANUFACTURER,
          .iProduct = STRINGID_PRODUCT,
          .iSerialNumber = STRINGID_SERIAL,
          .bNumConfigurations = 1
        };
    const struct usb_interface_descriptor if_descriptor = {
        .bLength = sizeof if_descriptor,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_INTERFACE,
        .bInterfaceNumber = 0,
        .bAlternateSetting = 0,
        .bNumEndpoints = 2,
        .bInterfaceClass = USB_CLASS_COMM,
        .bInterfaceSubClass = 0,
        .bInterfaceProtocol = 0,
        .iInterface = 0
    };
    const struct usb_config_descriptor config = {
        .bLength = sizeof config,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_CONFIG,
        .wTotalLength = sizeof config + sizeof if_descriptor,
        .bNumInterfaces = 1,
        .bConfigurationValue = 1,
        .iConfiguration = 0,
        .bmAttributes = USB_CONFIG_ATT_ONE | USB_CONFIG_ATT_SELFPOWER,
        .bMaxPower = 1
    };

    uint8_t init_config[2048];
    uint8_t* p = init_config;

    printf("Start init\n");
    *p++ = 0;
    *p++ = 0;
    *p++ = 0;
    *p++ = 0;

#define FETCH(desc)                             \
    memcpy(p, &desc, desc.bLength);             \
    p += desc.bLength;

    FETCH(config);
    FETCH(if_descriptor);
    FETCH(config);              /* again for a high-speed i/f */
    FETCH(if_descriptor);

    FETCH(device_descriptor);

    // Configure ep0
    int send_size = p - init_config;
    int sent = write(fd, init_config, send_size);

    if (sent != send_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Write error %d/%d (%m)\n", sent/send_size);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("ep0 configured\n");

    handle_ep0(fd);
}
```

Without changing the code, I unpredictably get two different results as seen from a Linux host using `lsusb -v -d aa00:00bb`.  When it works, I get:

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xaa00
  idProduct          0x00bb
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Toby
  iProduct                2 widget
  iSerial                 3 v1
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

And when it fails:

```
Bus 001 Device 027: ID aa00:00bb Toby widget
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xaa00
  idProduct          0x00bb
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 (error)
  iProduct                2 (error)
  iSerial                 3 (error)
  bNumConfigurations      1
```

And it won't work again until I unload the `dwc3` driver and re-load it.

Here's the relevant kernel log messages for the failing case (I enabled `CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VERBOSE` to get these):

> ```
> [342748.061482] gadgetfs: bound to dwc3-gadget driver
> [342748.066303] gadgetfs: bound to gadget device
> [342748.071482] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.344072] gadgetfs: connected
> [342748.347308] gadgetfs: event[0] = 1
> [342748.347929] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.352265] gadgetfs: disconnected
> [342748.355755] gadgetfs: event[0] = 2
> [342748.356315] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.504041] gadgetfs: connected
> [342748.507269] gadgetfs: event[0] = 1
> [342748.507842] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.510596] gadgetfs: delegate req80.06 v0300 i0000 l255
> [342748.510600] gadgetfs: event[0] = 3
> [342748.511208] gadgetfs: usb_ep_queue returned 0
> [342748.511213] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.511557] gadgetfs: delegate req80.06 v0302 i0028 l255
> [342748.511563] gadgetfs: event[0] = 3
> [342748.511630] gadgetfs: usb_ep_queue returned 0
> [342748.511635] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.511934] gadgetfs: delegate req80.06 v0301 i0028 l255
> [342748.511940] gadgetfs: event[0] = 3
> [342748.511989] gadgetfs: usb_ep_queue returned 0
> [342748.511995] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.512181] gadgetfs: delegate req80.06 v0303 i0028 l255
> [342748.512187] gadgetfs: event[0] = 3
> [342748.512232] gadgetfs: usb_ep_queue returned 0
> [342748.512238] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.512711] gadgetfs: configuration #1
> [342748.516551] gadgetfs: event[0] = 3
> [342748.517139] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> [342748.953968] gadgetfs: delegate req80.06 v0300 i0000 l4
> [342748.953974] gadgetfs: event[0] = 3
> [342748.954544] dwc3 38100000.usb: ep0out: pending_list empty
> [342748.960062] gadgetfs: usb_ep_queue returned -16
> [342748.960108] gadgetfs: ep0_read wait
> ```

(The line from `dwc` is the one I added to the `ret = -EBUSY` shown above).

A Wireshark trace perhaps points the finger at `SET_CONFIGURATION`, as it all works until that point:

```
No. Time           delta          Source    Length Info                                      Descriptor no
  1 0.000000       0.000000       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request DEVICE             0x00
  2 0.004048       0.004048       1.113.0   82     GET DESCRIPTOR Response DEVICE            
  3 0.004074       0.000026       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request CONFIGURATION      0x00
  4 0.004669       0.000595       1.113.0   73     GET DESCRIPTOR Response CONFIGURATION     
  5 0.004682       0.000013       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request CONFIGURATION      0x00
  6 0.005918       0.001236       1.113.0   110    GET DESCRIPTOR Response CONFIGURATION     
  7 0.005948       0.000030       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING             0x00
  8 0.570791       0.564843       1.113.0   68     GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING            
  9 0.570822       0.000031       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING             0x02
 10 0.571913       0.001091       1.113.0   86     GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING            
 11 0.571933       0.000020       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING             0x01
 12 0.572662       0.000729       1.113.0   84     GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING            
 13 0.572680       0.000018       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING             0x03
 14 0.573539       0.000859       1.113.0   98     GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING            
 15 0.573806       0.000267       host      64     SET CONFIGURATION Request                 
 16 0.578297       0.004491       1.113.0   64     SET CONFIGURATION Response                
 17 0.578325       0.000028       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING             0x04
 18 5.703230       5.124905       1.113.0   64     GET DESCRIPTOR Response                   
 19 5.703244       0.000014       host      64     GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING             0x04
 20 10.823171      5.119927       1.113.0   64     GET DESCRIPTOR Response
```

What could be causing this failure, and what do I need to do to avert it?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that seems to fix this.  I don't much like it, and there ought to be something not involving an arbitrary sleep!

I changed the set-configuration handler to wait for 10ms before replying, and also to test the result of writing the ACK.  Either one of these alone was insufficient.

```
    case USB_REQ_SET_CONFIGURATION:
        printf("Ignoring configuration value %d\n", setup->wValue);
        usleep(10'000);
        // Just ACK
        status = read(fd, &status, 0);
        if (status < 0) {
            goto stall;
        }
        return;
```